# Why does my Python code require me to convert a list into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

I am writing a Function for Minimizing any function, by changing some target parameter.

A strange phenomenon occurs that forces me to continuously (in a for loop) convert a list into a list. I would imagine that line 181 should be redundant, given that line 176 is present, but no. Without it, though no error occurs, the parameter value is huge, when I know for a fact, that it should be small (and is returned when the code is as shown below).

Here is what I tried:

1. print(type(func_args) at every stage in the process. pre conversion from tuple to list. post such conversion, inside the for loop, and inside the boolean - as expected... the very first type is a tuple and then everything is a list
2. In the for loop I wrote both print(func_args) and print(list((func_args))) - as expected the values in the list are the same.
3. And most ridiculous of all... even kinda ashamed to have tried it ... Inside the for loop, I assigned func_args to... func_args (func_args=func_args). As expected the value of the parameter goes off the rails in the same way as it did before.

I have no clue what the hell this is about. Any suggestions?

```
def krange(start, stop, step):

total_steps = int((stop-start)/step)
    
for each_step in range(total_steps):
     yield start
     start += step     


def Minimize(Function,start,end,step,var_index,*func_args): 
    
    min_value = Function(*func_args)    
    func_args = list(func_args)
    func_args_copy = func_args.copy()    
    
    for element in krange (start,end,step):#search space        
        
        func_args = list ( func_args )
        func_args[var_index] = func_args_copy[var_index] + element            
        
        if Function(*func_args) < min_value:
            
            min_value = Function(*func_args)         
            best_fit_args = func_args            
            
    return min_value, list(best_fit_args)
```

[To be clear as to which lines of code I refer to...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o86m.png)

Comment: And what is the type of func_args_copy?  I bet it's a tuple, and so on line 182 you're creating a new tuple and assigning it to func_args.

Comment: Additionally, please do not provide pictures of code.  Please copy and paste it into a code block into your question.  See: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I hope you didn't hide the code in that link, because I'm not going to click it. And your question is unanswerable without code.

Comment: @Max Nope. func_args_copy is always a list.

Comment: `best_fit_args = func_args` doesn't copy the current solution, it just gives another name for the existing object.  If you don't create a new copy of `func_args` on each iteration, then your subsequent modifications to `func_args` are also changing `best_fit_args`.  You really want `best_fit_args = func_args.copy()`, to take a snapshot of the solution.

Comment: @ I edited the body of the question, as per your request.

Comment: @jasonharper you did it! Paste your solution as an answer, not as a comment, so that I can end this question

Comment: I wouldn't worry about ending the question. You got the help you needed, and the question isn't worded in a way that will help others find it if they're having the same problem.